# Regular expressions in MySql

Tags: mysql, regex

In MySql (I'm using 5.1.48), the following regular expressions return `true` i.e `1`.

```
SELECT '10-5' REGEXP '10-5' as temp;
SELECT '10/5' REGEXP '10/5' as temp;
SELECT '1*5' REGEXP '1*5' as temp;
```

The following expressions however return `false` i.e `0`.

```
SELECT '10+5' REGEXP '10+5' as temp;
SELECT '10*5' REGEXP '10*5' as temp;
```

---

> To use a literal instance of a special character in a regular
>   expression, precede it by two backslash (\) characters. The MySQL
>   parser interprets one of the backslashes, and the regular expression
>   library interprets the other.

Escaping `+` and `*` in the preceding two statements returns `true` i.e `1` as follows.

```
SELECT '10+5' REGEXP '10\\+5' as temp;
SELECT '10*5' REGEXP '10\\*5' as temp;
```

If this is the case then why is `*` in the following statement (the last one in the first snippet) **not** required to escape?

```
SELECT '1*5' REGEXP '1*5' as temp;
```

It returns `true` i.e `1` without escaping `*` and the following something similar (the last one in the second snippet) returns `false`.

```
SELECT '10*5' REGEXP '10*5' as temp;
```

It requires `*` to be escaped. Why?

Comment: If you are lookging for exact match why not use `=` sign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An unescaped asterisk, as you know, means "zero or more of the preceeding character", so "1*5" means "any number of 1s, followed by a 5".

The key is this info from [the doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html):

```
 A REGEXP pattern match succeeds if the pattern matches anywhere in the value being tested. (This differs from a LIKE pattern match, which succeeds only if the pattern matches the entire value.)
```

So, "1*5" ("any number of 1s, followed by a 5") will match the string "1*5" by only seeing the "5".  "10*5" ("1, followed by any number of 0s, followed by a 5") won't match the string "10*5" because the "*" character breaks it up.

Hope that helps.